# Schedule task launching issue on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a task on windows 7 machine and it works pretty fine if I select option "Run only when user is logged on". However if try to run task using option "Run whether user is logged on or not" then nothing for some time. And history of task shows a launch error and get this error message:

```
Task Scheduler failed to launch action "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" in instance "{97eea12a-af59-4fdf-bb66-36f7c1c1d6a8}" of task xyz
```

Task "start in (optional)" path is provided without quotes. I am using windows 7 machine and task executes batch file. Batch file runs a small .Net application and then do the robocopying.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452175/schedule-task-launching-issue-on-windows-7) questions.

Comment: what is best way then ask on different forum? Anyway I specified in the heading that I has asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: @User1551892 | You wouldn't ask on different StackExchange forums. You post on the one most relevant to the question you are asking. This way you are more likely to find a solid answer and avoid having your question closed.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams: I have removed this question from stackoverflow. Please remove on hld

Answer (score 0):

In my case, batch file exists on a file server rather than existing on local machine and due to which I was getting this problem. However, when I moved my batch file on local machine then this error disappear and everything worked smoothly.